# Adjusting radiofield ticker to center

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2

So here's my radiofield that i have

[image]

All the icons are already centered, but the radio tickers are not... i tried to fix this in the inspector, as shown in the code below

```
.x-field-radio .x-field-mask::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 26px;
height: 26px;
top: 11px;
left: auto;
right: 11px;
background-color: #dddddd;
-webkit-border-radius: 26px;
-moz-border-radius: 26px;
-ms-border-radius: 26px;
-o-border-radius: 26px;
border-radius: 26px;
}

.x-field-radio .x-field-mask::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
top: 16px;
left: auto;
right: 16px;
background-color: #d0d0d0;
-webkit-border-radius: 16px;
-moz-border-radius: 16px;
-ms-border-radius: 16px;
-o-border-radius: 16px;
border-radius: 16px;
}
```

Where i changed the before:left to 35% and after:left to 41% to make it look centered.

However this solution is temporary only because when i tried to adjust the inspector size to see the effect of inspector size on the ticker, the ticker became totally off from the center.

So i like to know if there's any other possible solution to center the radio ticker regardless of the screen size. I looked into Sencha Touch documentations, but couldn't found any that could resolve my problem.

EDIT: Include the view of the code below (i changed the icons to text instead) if anyone can help me try this on jsfiddle..

```
Ext.define('view.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'radiotest',

    requires: [
        'Ext.form.*',
        'Ext.field.*',
        'Ext.Button',
        'Ext.Toolbar',
        'Ext.TitleBar'
    ],

    config: {

        defaults: {
            required: true
        },

        items: [
            {
               xtype: 'container',
               id: 'radioPanel',
               items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'fieldset',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        title: 'Put label in here',
                        defaults: { 
                            xtype: 'radiofield',
                            labelAlign: 'top',
                            width: '20%',
                        },
                        items: [
                            { name : 'name1', label: '<p style="text-align:center">Icon1</p>', value: '1' },
                            { name : 'name2', label: '<p style="text-align:center">Icon2</p>', value: '2' },
                            { name : 'name3', label: '<p style="text-align:center">Icon3</p>', value: '3' },
                            { name : 'name4', label: '<p style="text-align:center">Icon4</p>', value: '4' },
                            { name : 'name5', label: '<p style="text-align:center">Icon5</p>', value: '5' }
                        ]
                    }
               ]
            },

        ]
    },

});
```

Comment: if you give a jsfiddle link to markup, we will be able to help!!! :)

Comment: I tried putting the view code into jsfiddle (together with the sencha touch libraries and css) but it shown nothing on the result panel.. so i include the view code in my question above in case if you could help me on testing it in jsfiddle. Sorry ><

Comment: is the code live somewhere...can you provide url to it???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/88Cm5/ but i dunno what went wrong with my fiddle...

Comment: there is no html or css in the fiddle...only js is there...thats what went wrong!! :)

Comment: But like this one http://jsfiddle.net/lozenlin/yU6t6/light/ the author didn't include the html, only css.. and the css i think is generated automatically with sencha libraries at the ext resources..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44169/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-fred-a)